# How to create Qrcode image from bitmatrix in mono touch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using **zXing.net.monotouch.dll** library for creating QRCode in monotouch. I got the bitmatrix by using the following code. I don't know how to convert it to image. In net everybody using the **com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix** but it is not supported in my program. Please find me a solution:

```
ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeWriter ObjQrCodeWriter= new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeWriter();
ZXing.Common.BitMatrix bitMatrix1=ObjQrCodeWriter.encode("this is a string content",ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,60,60);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the class ZXing.BarcodeWriter.

```
var writer = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
{ 
   Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 
   Options = new EncodingOptions { Height = 60, Width = 60 } 
};
var image = writer.Write("this is a string content");
```